# Artifactory parameters in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am using the Artifactory Jenkins plugin to publish artifacts using the Generic-Artifactory Integration. I would like to be able to refer to the Artifactory Server URL and Target Repository as variables later on in a build script.

Does Artifactory expose these parameters as accessible variables? If so, what are they?

The only other option I have thought of is creating my own variables using the Environment Variable Injector plugin and referencing those variables in the Artifactory fields.

I would prefer to go with option 1.